# IBOutlet release

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, iboutlet

Are the unsafe_unretained IBOutlet objects released when a view disappears (`viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`) or are they released when the view unloads (`viewDidUnload`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBOutlets should never form a strong retain-relationship to their View Controller because they are not owned by it.  So in effect, they are just released when the view controller passes out of context.  Because of their extremely weak references, they are deallocated when the view controlle is deallocated, which can occur at any time.  There is no specific function.